# How to detect tapped word in WebView?

Tags: react-native

I have a simple WebView and would like to know which word in it was tapped. For example if a user taps on any of the words in the article on the picture, such as "balloon", I would like to capture that.

Here is the code and the render.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{top:100, height: 500, backgroundColor:'red' }}>
        <WebView
          source={{uri: 'https://www.reuters.com/article/us-art-banksy/we-just-got-banksy-ed-balloon-girl-painting-self-destructs-at-sale-idUSKCN1MG0B4?feedType=RSS&feedName=artsNews'}}
          style={{height:"200", marginTop: 20}}
        />
      </View>

    );
  }
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**
This is how I got WebView to communicate back the JS events based on @pritesh answer.

```
<WebView
          source={{uri: 'https://www.reuters.com/article/us-art-banksy/we-just-got-banksy-ed-balloon-girl-painting-self-destructs-at-sale-idUSKCN1MG0B4?feedType=RSS&feedName=artsNews'}}
          style={{height:"200", marginTop: 20}}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          injectedJavaScript={`document.body.addEventListener('click', 
        function(e){
          window.postMessage("Message from WebView","*");
          console.log(e);
        })`}
          onMessage={e => console.log("message", e)}
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

On top of my head one approach you can try is by using the [injectJavascript](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview#injectjavascript) or `injectedJavascript` props of WebView.So you can register some kind of listener on the body and the use it to detect what is being pressed, like:

```
<WebView
    ref={c => this._webview = c}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    injectedJavaScript={`document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        console.log(e)
    })`}
/>
```

But you check to research how to pass the callback from Webview to React.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped get closer to the desired outcome.